# Not able to add Email as a tab in Salesforce LEX

Tags: email, tabs, salesforce-lightning

There is no option to add Email as a tab to the tab section in app builder / edit page layout.
I mean this:
[image: SF tabs section]

even though it is added in Mobile and Lightning Experience in page layout.

how is it supposed to be done?

is there a correct way?

if not, is there a get-around way to add it?